# Deploy Docker container in EC2 base on Repository URI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2

I have an Ec2 on AWS.

I tried

- SSH into that box
- install Docker
- pull Docker image from my : `Repository URI`

`docker pull bheng-api-revision-test:latest 616934057156.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-api-revision-test:latest`

- tag it

`docker tag bheng-api-revision-test:latest 616934057156.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-api-revision-test:latest`

I'm trying to build it, and I don't know what command I should use.

I've tried

`docker build bheng-api-revision-test:latest 616934057156.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-api-revision-test:latest .`

I kept getting

[image]

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: You have a Dockerfile?

Comment: You don't pull a image and build it like that. You need the source of how the image was built and then only you can rebuild the image using the `docker build` command

Comment: @TonyStark, I don't have anything in my new EC2. It's new. I just spin it up from AWS.

Comment: @TarunLalwani, please elaborate a bit more or kindly answer.